# Динамическое создание tab

Tags: java, android, tabs, tab, android-tabs

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку создавался новый таб с какой-то информацией. Подскажите, по какому запросу гуглить и что следует почитать на эту тему. Огромное спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо пользовать самое свежее решение: [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) из `android.support.design` либы от гугла

1. Добавляем библиотеку в `build.gradle` вместе с библиотекой поддержки:

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   ```
2. Создаём/находим в разметке `TabLayout`

   ```
   TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
   ```
3. На лету создаём и добавляем табы:

   ```
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 111111111111"));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 222222222222"));
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 333333333333"));
   ```